# How to successfully serve the react app through express js server and csrf token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I was tasked with adding an additional layer of security by adding csrf token. I was able add the csurf package along with cookie parser but I am having issues with react and passing the token to react. I cant post my code here but maybe these specific lines listed below are enough to answer the question.

```js
**//this line here is causing issues because if I remove the get route the index.html will still be servered regardless of whether or not I include the get route request!** 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

//if i comment this get route out the react app is still being served
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  //added this console log to see if this was even being called and it is NOT being called
  console.log('get request called');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Before I can even get to the csrf token I need to figure out why the get route is not being ran. Question: Why is the react application still being served even if i remove the get route? Is it something with the app.use(express.static...) line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes express.static is serving the index file from your build folder.

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. How can i ensure though that the get request is the one to serve the page instead of that static site being served without?

Comment: you can set option in static {index=false} , then route.use("/your/path/name",express,static(folderPath,option)) . Setting index to false will make sure static won't use the index as a default option. Setting folder path will make sure that "/" will not refer to static. So requesting static resource will start with /url/your/path/name